# そうですか versus そうなんですか

Tags: grammar

When do I have to use

> そうですか。

and

> そうなんですか。

?

Comment: This is actually a super-advanced question despite the way you make it look like.  Each phrase has multiple different nuances depending on how it is said with regards to intonation, stress, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have to use?  Well, any time you want to, as long as you mean "is it?" or "is that so?"  ;-)

So much for kidding.

Do you want to differentiate between the two? They mean the same thing, with the latter revealing a bit of surprise/scepticism/unexpectedness etc, depending on the context.

Comment: +10000: How about あそうですか and そうですか?

Comment: If "そうですか?" stands for "is it?" or "is that so?", then "あそうですか" stands for "ah, is it?" or "ah, is that so?" Does this make sense?

Comment: I'm sorry to downvote, but both phrases can mean other things, such as 'I see'.