# What does もんなんすかねぇ actually mean?

Tags: readings, slang

[image]
[image]

> それって教師がなんかしてどうにかなるもんなんすかねぇ

What is actually this sentence trying to say? The character is a teacher and he got told starting the second year his students will need more 個々の実力 and he think this

I understand is それって教師がなんかして is akin to "About that, a teacher, somehow...." however what does どうにかなるもんなんすかねぇ mean here?

Comment: This is a contraction.  Do you know what it is a contraction of?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to identify. どうにかなる　+ もの + なんですか?

Comment: That can still be expanded further: なんですか= なのですか where な is the copula だ as it is used when a modifier.

Answer (score 3):

If you understand it is どうにかなる + もの + なんですか, you are almost there.

First, なん in なんですか generally does not add (much) meaning.

- [そうですか versus そうなんですか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25632/45489)
- [The difference between [noun phrase]+[？・なの？・ですか？・なんですか？]](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18400/45489)

So you can think about どうにかなる**ものですか**, which can be more or less understood literally, i.e., ***is it a thing** that (教師がなんかして)どうにかなる.

どうにかなる is ambiguous, but here it means '(things) work out'. See the following question for some more details.

- [Can someone explain to me the grammatical structure of this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/97562/45489)

教師がなんかしてどうにかなるもの means literally: *a thing that teachers do something about and works out* (although you still need to understand subject/object relationship correctly).

Making it a bit more idiomatic, the sentence means *is it something teachers can do anything to improve*?

Comment: But isn't ものですか used to express absolute negation?  https://www.google.com/amp/s/nihongokyoshi-net.com/2019/06/03/jlptn2-grammar-monoka/%3famp=1

Comment: @Kawase_K There are several meanings/usages of ものですか. It's not used that way in the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

もんなんすか is colloquialism for ものなのですか.

- **それって**: "regarding that" (=個々の実力)
- **教師がなんかして**: "a teacher does something (and...)"
- **どうにかなる** (≈ なんとかなる): "end up with something", "works out", "manage somehow"

  - [Can someone explain to me the grammatical structure of this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/97562/5010)
- **もの(な)**: "... is generally the case", "... is usually true"

  - [How to parse 親も辞書を買ってやったかいがあるってもんだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28872/5010)
  - [もの in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/98575/5010)
  - [What is the use of ものでしょうか in this context? 「今から治療して間に合うものでしょうか？」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/100908/5010)
- **の**: explanatroy-no
- **ですかね?**: "Is it ...?"

So a super-literal translation is "Regarding that, is it that it is (generally) something where a teacher does something and ends up with something?". A smoother translation would be "Is that really something that can be managed by a teacher doing something?"